# Dynamic job scheduling with earliest time and deadline

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

I have a real life algorithmic problem and I'm trying to find out if there is any similar widely known algorithmic problem with known solutions that I could adapt to my particular use case.

I want to solve a kind of scheduling problem: I have a machine that will be processing jobs and I want to fit them into a schedule.

The capacity of the machine is limited within discrete time units (for example hours). During every given time unit $t$ the machine can process a limited number of work units - $u(t)$.

There are job queries coming one by one (they aren't all known upfront), each job $j$ has:

- the earliest time it can start to be processed by the machine $j_{et}$ - so it can only be processed if $t \ge j_{et}$
- the deadline $j_{ft}$ when it has to be finished - so it can only be processed when $t \lt j_{ft}$
- number of work units it takes to process it - $j_u $

The job has to be finished "in one go" - once a job is started by the machine the job has to be finished before any other job is started.

For each incoming job query I need to be able to:

- tell if it is possible to add the job to the schedule or it has to be rejected
- add the job to the schedule if possible

The closest problems I've found are:

- "[Job Sequencing with Deadline](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms_job_sequencing_with_deadline.htm)"
  but in case of this problem jobs are known upfront (so the algorithm is static) and some of them may not meet the deadline.
- "[Multiprocessor scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling)"  which in case of identical processors references "[Multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning)"
  but as I understand they seem to be more focused on separating the job between multiple processors while in my case I have only one machine.

Is there anything 'closer' to what I described? I would appreciate any hints or references that could inspire me solve this particular problem.

Comment: Please state your goal - what would an optimal solution look like? Least number of rejections? Lowest average latency for starting tasks? Lowest worst-case latency for starting tasks? Highest possible busy percentage for the machine? These are all conflicting optima.

Comment: @orlp The goal is to accept the job if it is possible to schedule it without breaking time constraints for any already scheduled jobs. So it's a bit like "least number of rejections" but as it needs to schedule them one by one without knowing "future" jobs it should just try to fit every incoming job if that's possible.

Comment: Must the process schedule the task if it is able to, or is the ultimate goal the least number of rejections? There is a difference, suppose the algorithm keeps track of the average task length, and a task comes in that is much, much larger than the average task length it can choose to reject it in the assumption more smaller tasks will come later.

Comment: @orlp you're right, it could be possible to try to guess whether jobs that come later could use the capacity better but I don't want to do that. The algorithm must answer "yes" the given job can be scheduled given all the previously scheduled jobs. Also, the job-query process is time-sensitive (a synchronous API call) so it might be needed to sacrifice some accuracy for the speed. The predicted machine load is around ~1k jobs in given time unit and each job having a time constraint window of around 10 time units. We can assume around 20 time units in an independent problem space.

Comment: Final question, do the tasks come in one by one or in batches?

Comment: @orlp One by one